# adb not working in powershell but adb.exe works

Tags: android, powershell, adb, command-precedence

when typing "`adb devices`" in Powershell, it return a prompt to ask "`How do you want to open this file`". 
[image: screenshot for the prompt]
However, if I use "`adb.exe devices`", it works and give me the list of devices.

As I have a lot of scripts written as adb instead of adb.exe, is there a way to fix this?

In cmd, typing adb devices would also work. But the scripts were all PS based. So fixing this in powershell will really helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've confirmed, the problem was an extraneous, empty file literally named `adb` (without a filename extension) that resided in your `C:\WINDOWS\system32` directory.

Since the `PATH` environment variable (typically) lists `C:\WINDOWS\system32` *before* the directory in which the desired target executable (`adb.exe`) is located, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Platform\...`, PowerShell attempted to execute `C:\WINDOWS\system32\adb`, which - as an extension-less file - triggered the GUI dialog you saw.

Removing the extraneous `C:\WINDOWS\system32\adb` file solved your problem.

`Get-Command -All adb` helped discovered the problem: it listed all forms of a command named `adb` known to PowerShell, in order of precedence, with information about their type and location; that is, the *effective* command - the one that is actually invoked - was listed first.

Read on for background information.

---

- As all shells do, if a command uses a *mere (file) name* (as opposed to a *file path*), PowerShell looks for executables in the directories listed in the `PATH` environment variable (accessible as `$env:PATH` in PowerShell), *in order*.

  - That is, if you submit a command line with command name `adb`, PowerShell - after looking for an *internal* command by that name first (an alias, function, or cmdlet) - looks for an *executable file* whose *base name* is `adb`, in the directories listed in `$env:PATH`, and invokes the *first* one it finds.
  - On Windows, an executable file is one whose *filename extension* is listed in the `PATHEXT` environment variable (`$env:PATHEXT`); again, the extensions listed there are considered *in order*. By contrast, on Unix-like platforms it is solely the *file mode* (the permission bits) that determine whether a file is executable.
- However, **unlike other shells, PowerShell doesn't just look for *executable* files in `$env:PATH`, it considers *any* file that *exactly* matches the command name given executable, and in effect passes such a file to the [`Invoke-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Invoke-Item) cmdlet**, which triggers the default GUI shell action on the file, equivalent to double-clicking a document in File Explorer on Windows.

  - This problematic behavior is discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12632), which proposes that only true executables be considered commands.

Comment: I have no idea what this answer means.  I have the sdktools installed in the AppData folder which was done by android studio.  I have included the tools in the Path but it does not work.  And furthermore, if I go directly there, it says I must use .\adb.exe  but when I try adb attach it gives adb.exe: failed to attach: attach/detach only implemented for libusb backend  .  That is how I came here

Comment: @BhikkhuSubhuti, I have no idea what your comment means. It sounds like you have a question that differs from the one in this post, so you should create a _new_ question post, focused on your specific problem.

Comment: In short.. I have zero problems with linux which is my main driver.  Never did anything special.  Windows "just does not work"  even when I directly type adb.exe or .\adb.exe